# How to calculate a formula contain different columns from different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have to calculate "totalAmountCollected + endingReceivables - totalSalesDone"

All three columns from three dataframes. There is one common column in three dataframes is clientCode.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Join the three dataframes on the client code and then create a new column based on the computation you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on="clientCode").merge(df3, on="clientCode").fillna(0)

df['result'] = df.totalAmountCollected + df.endingReceivables - df.totalSalesDone
```

If the clients population is not the same in all three dataframes, you may want to consider left or outer joins.

Comment: Thanks, I will try